# SpringBoot adds context path to Actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, contextpath

I am running my springboot application by setting context-path to /myservice. This results into appending all my actuator endpoints exposed at the URL- http://localhost:8080/myservice/actuator/*, while I want only http://localhost:8080/actuator/*.
Is there a way to tell the springboot to ignore appending context path to actuator endpoints (through DispatcherServlet or CXFServlet or anything)
Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

From the documentation:

> Unless the management port has been configured to expose endpoints by
> using a different HTTP port, management.endpoints.web.base-path is
> relative to server.servlet.context-path (Servlet web applications) or
> spring.webflux.base-path (reactive web applications). If
> management.server.port is configured,
> management.endpoints.web.base-path is relative to
> management.server.base-path.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.monitoring.customizing-management-server-context-path

What you could do is to use a different port for the management endpoints.

```
management.server.port=8081
```

Then you will get http://localhost:8081/actuator

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is not possible because spring boot has only one `DispatcherServlet` which is a front controller, if you want two different paths then you can use `@RequestMapping` annotation on two different controllers`

Still of you want two different context-paths then you should have two `DispatcherServlet's`